# Radio button product attribute?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute

**Magento 2.3.3**

I am trying to create a product attribute which has the type "radio button". I am almost sure in Magento 1 it was possible to do just that. Now in Magento 2, I do not have the option "radio button" as type of option, only dropdown and some others. Am I missing something, or is it not possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you looking for Custom Options or Product Attribute?

Answer (score 0):

**Create Attribute** following way :-

```
 $eavSetup->updateAttribute(
         \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY, 'custom_attribute_name', 
    [
        'type' => 'int',
        'backend' => 'Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Backend\ArrayBackend',
        'frontend' => '',
        'label' => 'Custom Attribute Name',
        'input' => 'boolean',
        'group' => 'General',
        'class' => 'custom_attribute_name',
        'source' => 'Custom\Product\Model\YesNo',
        'global' => ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
        'visible' => true,
        'required' => true,
        'user_defined' => false,
        'default' => '1',
        'searchable' => false,
        'filterable' => false,
        'comparable' => false,
        'visible_on_front' => false,
        'used_in_product_listing' => true,
        'unique' => false
    ]
    );
```

After you add options like. Create File **`Custom\Product\Model\YesNo`** For Options

```
<?php
namespace Yourvendorname\Yourmodulename\Model;

class YesNo extends \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\Source\AbstractSource
{

    protected $_options;

    public function toOptionArray()
    {
         return array(
            array('value' => '1', 'label' => __('Yes')),
            array('value' => '0', 'label' => __('No'))
            ..................
         );
     }
     public function getAllOptions()
    {
        return $this->toOptionArray();
    }
}
```

You Can Add Options In toOptionArray() Function

**`THANKS.`**